# OK / Cancel buttons order in ICS

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

Since SDK 14, the preferred order is Cancel / OK in opposition to OK / Cancel before.
I am NOT going to enter in the debate of whether it is a good o bad idea, this is not the subject of my question.

The thing is that the ADK encourages you to use the new order for devices with SDK >= 14 by giving you the following Lint

> Layout uses the wrong button order for API >= 14: Create a
>   layout-v14/layout.xml file with opposite order: Cancel
>   button should be on the left (was "@string/send | Cancel", should be
>   "Cancel | @string/ send")

OK, I will stick to that, this is not a problem for me and I understand that I should follow the advice in order to avoid annoying the users.

But here is the thing... On my Samsung Galaxy S II, running on ICS, the System interface itself seem not to follow the new order. Here are a few screenshot examples:

[image]

The order is the old one.
Note that I use the official ICS version for my phone (not a custom ROM). And the order is the same on my Galaxy Tab 2 (also running official ICS).
On some dialogs, the order is correct (cancel / OK)
The only difference I see is the Theme (the dialogs using the Holo theme have the new order; the others, the old order). Here is a screenshot of a DatePickerDialog from the settings (to set the system date) and from my app using Holo:

[image]

This is quite disturbing.
It looks like the order of the buttons is Theme-related and not version-related.
Or is it just Samsung not following Android's design patterns?

I think that Activities (when they have OK / Cancel buttons) should also follow the same order. And here, again, on my phone the Create Event activity of the Calendar has the wrong order (And the activity does not use Hole theme):

[image]

I will be using the Holo theme in my app for devices as from Honeycomb anyway, so I will keep the new order for SDK>=14. I just would like to understand this ussue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the button swap is quite irritating and i end up hitting cancel more than the ok button. But this is what you can do. Either create your own custom dialog box so that you keep control of which button comes where, else let the user figure out by reading. Only thing we need to do as programmers is so to it that when cancel is pressed, it actually cancels and not OKays! To shed more light on why Ok-Cancel was swapped, this was to avoid Patent infringement with Apple as they too follow Ok-Cancel. So swapping Cancel-Ok would mean no infringement(Silly, but saves Google Millions!)

Comment: The amount of stupidity of this gave you +1 from me ;) how can apple have patent on something windows have used for years? Or maybe microsoft and apple both have patent on this. Would you happen to be able to produce a reference to your statements?

Comment: @Royston - As I said, The question is not on what I should do or not. On SDK>=14 the order must be followed (Cancel / OK) and this is what I'm going to do. The question here is to understand why some system dialogs have the wrong order.

Comment: Its not that they have the wrong order, but upto OEM's must have named Positive button as cancel and Negative Button as OK thus changing the order. Even you could do that. It's not a hard and fast rule that it should be followed.

Comment: Apple doesn't do Ok-Cancel - they do Cancel-Ok. The Mac and iOS HIG have always been this way. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-TP9 http://cdn.mactrast.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/greentree-warning3.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Samsung have this weird idea about maintaining the Touchwiz look and feel from Android 2 into Android 4.x devices. It's the single most annoying thing about Samsung 4.x ROMs for me personally as the ICS/JB UI is much nicer. It's most noticeable in dialogs (using 2.x button arrangement as you mentioned) and tabs (using 2.x tabs rather than the much nicer 4.x tabs).

Even the newer 4.x only devices like the SGS3 (assume the Note 2 also which has just been released) still have this ridiculous porting of Android 2 UI components.

I suspect this is not an issue for end users so much as it's annoying for developers that have many devices and notice the differences.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it seems the order of the buttons is theme related, not version related. In difference to layout "alert_dialog.xml" the "alert_dialog_holo.xml" puts "button1" (positive) right and "button2" (negative) left.

The layout is determined by com.android.internal.app.AlertController:

```
public AlertController(Context context, DialogInterface di, Window window) {

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(null,
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.AlertDialog,
            com.android.internal.R.attr.alertDialogStyle, 0);

    mAlertDialogLayout = a.getResourceId(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AlertDialog_layout,
            com.android.internal.R.layout.alert_dialog);
```

The Theme's attribute "alertDialogStyle" refers to a "AlertDialog" style, which is a set of attributes that describe a AlertDialog's theme, the attribute "layout" may point to a layout resource, otherwise layout/alert_dialog is used.

In android source you can see that "Theme.Holo" uses "AlertDialog.Holo" which in turn referes to "layout/alert_dialog_holo", while "Theme" uses "AlertDialog" which contains no layout and defaults to the code's value.

themes.xml:

```
<style name="Theme">
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@android:style/AlertDialog</item>

<style name="Theme.Holo">
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@android:style/AlertDialog.Holo</item>
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AlertDialog">
    …
</style>

<style name="AlertDialog.Holo" parent="AlertDialog">
    …
    <item name="layout">@android:layout/alert_dialog_holo</item>
    …
</style>
```

The actually used theme seems to be defined by device defaults.

themes_device_defaults.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.DeviceDefault" parent="Theme.Holo" >
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@android:style/AlertDialog.DeviceDefault</item>
```

styles_device_defaults.xml:

```
<style name="AlertDialog.DeviceDefault" parent="AlertDialog.Holo">
</style>
```

I guess Samsung simply sets something else here, to maintain their look and feel as Philio described.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its the Samsung who made changes to the their ROM for Galaxy S2. I feel like they are a little notorious when it comes to do customization. In past, I had also been experiencing some issues with core Bluetooth operations in their ROMs for SGS2, xCover etc. So i wouldn't be surprised if it only happens in Samsung devices :)